# Monitor window opening, closing, DOMContentLoaded events for all current & future windows+tabs

Tags: javascript, firefox, screen-scraping, xul

**Background:**

I'm *authorised* to "automate" a 3rd party site for the purpose of pushing "service orders" into it and monitoring the progress of those requests.

I tried taking a normal "scraping" approach (using `WWW::Mechanize`, `HTML::Query`, etc from Perl) but ran into a *lot* of issues predicting what the JavaScript in the site would do under a variety of circumstances. I intend to go back to this approach if I ever receive support from the vendor of the product which runs the 3rd party site, or can get hold of some better documentation w.r.t business-rules of the product.

To avoid second guessing the JavaScript code, and to save a lot of time, I ended up taking an approach were I load the 3rd party site in Firefox on a dedicated VM, and then execute "privileged" code (i.e: nsI*) in the context of the site to "drive" and "scrape" the site.

I'm currently using `nsIWebProgressListener`/`DOMContentLoaded` (when I already have a reference to a ChromeWindow), and `nsIWindowMediator` window+tab enumeration called from `setInterval` to find new windows and tabs (when I have no way to predict them opening, nor gain a reference to their DOMWindow objects due to scoping of 3rd party JavaScript).

**Question:**
How can I automatically install a "hook" into each Window/Tab opened now (and in the future) by the 3rd party site's JavaScript? Something like a "window watcher" `nsI~` interface for the whole of the Firefox UI would be very useful in this case.

Comment: Essentially you want to replace polling (`setInterval`) with a listener?

Comment: Is this something that you could use a browser automater like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for?

Comment: @h0tw1r3 I'd like to be able to register a listener so that I can supply a callback for each of the appropriate events.

Comment: @RichardTowers Unfortunately, no. Selenium can no more predict the business logic of the application than I can. I really need to capture each window/tab as it's created.

Comment: @RichardTowers I can't predict when a new Window will open (see point about business rules). However once I've (somehow) detected that a new Window has opened, I can use `document.location` and `window.opener` and the contents of the `document` to determine its relationship to "current" window in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways you could do this, so the right choice depends on how you're going about everything else.

Here are just a few ways of listening, rather than polling.

1. New Chrome Windows

   ```
   function ChromeWindowObserver() {
       this.observe = function(subject, topic, data) {
          // subject is a ChromeWindow
       }
   }
   Components.classes["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1"]
         .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowWatcher)
         .registerNotification(new ChromeWindowObserver());
   ```
2. New Tabs

   ```
   function tabListener(event) {
       var browser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(event.target):
   }
   gBrowser.tabContainer.addEventListener("TabOpen", tabListener, false);
   ```
3. [Observer Notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications) (my favorite)

   ```
   const dumpObserver = {
       observe: function(subject, topic, data) { dump(topic + "\n"); }
   }
   const domObserver = {
       observe: function(subject, topic, data) { dump(subject.location + "\n"); }
   }
   const ObserverService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
         .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);

   /* debug log notifications */
   ObserverService.addObserver(dumpObserver, "*", false);
   /* debug log all new content locations */
   ObserverService.addObserver(domObserver, "content-document-global-created", false);
   ```

Side note, check out [JavaScript code modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_code_modules/Using).  I think that might be helpful for you when sharing data between chrome windows.

Comment: Ok, so if I force all new windows to be in tabs (browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction = 0) I can use `TabOpen` events on the `tabContainer` to see new tabs, and then `load` events on their `contentWindow`s to get the `DOMWindow`s. Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: I was already using `nsiWindowMediator` (Window Listener - `onOpenWindow`) to see new Chrome Windows opening, but I had to install the listener on each new Chrome Window. The `ChromeWindowObserver` seems a much more simple approach!

Comment: As I didn't write the application, I don't really need to do much sharing (it's all *global* and declare before any `ChromeWindow`s have opened) - I just need to drive & follow the interace, inject/extract some data. I can definitely see how code modules would be useful in a multi-window interface for an XULRunner app!